# Angular CLI ng new throws "npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing"

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli, angular-cli-v6

When I try to create a new project with Angular CLI, `ng new project-name`, I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...+EuGeFfIM3zMCaRLePh7u'
```

Screenshot of the error:

[image]

What can I do to solve this error?

Comment: Please edit your question to simplify it and let us understand it easily

Comment: Try this angular github issue.
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8572
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11311

My guess is you need to do a ` npm cache clean --force`.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know what you're trying to do, but this problem usually happens because of npm cache, so, first clean npm cache with following command and then try again.

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please edit your post so that it (a) relates to the question ("this" and "that" is a bit misleading) and (b) that you explain why/ how your suggestion solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

you should probably update your [angular cli](https://cli.angular.io/) version:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
ng new my-app
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and it was after a forced reboot due to a crash, at least I think so, I don't remember doing anything else unusual. However, somehow npm cache was corrupted.

To solve it I followed this [guide](https://dev.to/rishiabee/npm-err-unexpected-end-of-json-input-while-parsing-near-743), basically the solution is:

1. Clean npm cache: `npm cache clean --force`
2. Verify the contents of the cache folder: `npm cache verify`

This second command doesn't make much sense to me after clearing the cache. Perhaps I am ignoring some facts about how the npm cache works.

If the **error persists** after that, in my case it did, then try updating npm: `npm i npm@latest -g`.

I never knew if only with `npm cache verify` and/or `npm i npm@latest -g` the error could be solved.